# 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: python-3.x

I stck in 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Please, someone, share your best answer for it. What should I do now, this was my first Django project.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing could be attributed to a missing python3.exe file sometimes or that python3 is not defined.

You could try:

```
python "filename.py"
```

or

```
py -2 "filename.py" || py -3 "filename.py"
```